# I followed up the instructions to extend the column width and it reverts the number

Tags: pages

I am not sure why I try to update the number of the column width, but once I click out of the box, it reverts back to the original width. What can I do to keep the value I type?
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Which instructions did you follow?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question with the screenshot of what I am trying to update but as soon as I click out from there, it reverts to the original "4.4597 in"

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, that’s very helpful. Can you add a link to the instructions you were following?

Comment: This one: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3892583

Comment: Hi Martha! please use @ tagging to ping people you reply to. one person per comment.  cc: @grg